# How to take id of dynamic <p> tag and to change its background color when clicking on it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

following is the code

```
 foreach($this->categoryResult as $CatResult)
    {
        echo "<div id=".$CatResult['id']." onclick='$(this).css('background-color','#1adec9')'><p id=".$CatResult['id']." class='CatgrySelect' onClick='load_subcategory(".$CatResult['id'].")'>".$CatResult['description']." > </p></div>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' class='CatID' name='CatID' value=".$CatResult['id'].">";
        //echo $CatResult['id'];
    }
```

Comment: and your problem is...? Other than the bad usage of quotes in your onclick probably utterly killing the JS, the basics of what you have are how you'd go about it.

Comment: You CANNOT have 2 elements with the same ID in a valid HTML. Moreover your HTML in not well formatted, there is no ' or " aroud the ID value for example..

Comment: I think your single quotes are messing up your code. onclick is probably being interpreted like this: onclick='$(this).css(' , instead of the entire function. try using '\' before the inside quotes

Comment: and, like matrt said, avoid using the same id.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept called [Unobstrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
$(document).on('click', 'p.CatgrySelect', function(eV) {
     var pItem = $(this);
     var divItem = $(this).parents("div:first");

     pItem.css({"background-color":"#abc"});
     divItem.css({"background-color":"#cba"});
});
```

If you can reference any other parent DOM element that contains this dynamic DOM element you can replace it for `document` on the event listener.

Comment: `'document'` should be `document`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The background color of <p> tag is now changing when clicking on it. But i want that when selecting each p tag, the previously selected <p> tag's color should be transparent and the background color should be there for currently  selected <p> tag. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<div id=".$CatResult['id']." onclick='$(this).css(\'background-color\',\'#1adec9\')'>
```

adding a '\' before something like a quote general tells a text parser that you'd like avoid splitting the string at that point

Answer (score 0):

**looks like you have two IDS with the same name.. that is invalide.. ID should always be unique**

try this

```
foreach($this->categoryResult as $CatResult)
{
    echo "<div><p id=".$CatResult['id']." class='CatgrySelect' >".$CatResult['description']." > </p></div>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' class='CatID' name='CatID' value=".$CatResult['id'].">";
    //echo $CatResult['id'];
}
```

**javascript**

```
 $('document').on('click', 'p.CatgrySelect', function() {
   var p = $(this);
   var div = p.parent();

   p.css({"background-color":"#abc"});
   div.css({"background-color":"#cba"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($this->categoryResult as $CatResult)
 {
   echo "<div id='".$CatResult['id']."'><p id='".$CatResult['id']."' class='CatgrySelect'>".$CatResult['description']."</p></div>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' class='CatID' name='CatID' value='".$CatResult['id']."'>";
    //echo $CatResult['id'];
 }

 $(".CatgrySelect").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().css('background-color','#1adec9');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($this->categoryResult as $CatResult)
{
     echo "<div id='".$CatResult['id']."'><p id='".$CatResult['id']."' class='CatgrySelect'>".$CatResult['description']."</p></div>";
     echo "<input type='hidden' class='CatID' name='CatID' value='".$CatResult['id']."'>";
    //echo $CatResult['id'];
}
```

try this jquery/javascript:

```
$(".CatgrySelect").live('click',(function(){
     $(this).parent().css('background-color','#1adec9');
});
```